# Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior in Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have been working on an admin-Ui project. where I require to display data in a table format and do some pagination.
Firstly I have used use effect to fetch some data from an API on page load.

```js
function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get(config.endpoint);
            setData(res.data);
            setFilteredData(res.data);
        };
        getData();
    }, []);

    //Handling Search
    const handleSearch = (text) => {
        setFilteredData(performSearch(text, data));
    };

    //paging;
    const end = page * config.pageSize;
    const start = end - config.pageSize;

    const filterData = data.slice(start, end);
    //change Page Function
    const handlePage = (num) => setPage(num);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Search handleSearch={handleSearch} />
            <UserTable data={filterData} />
            {/* <Pages handlePaginate={handlePage} dataLength={data.length} /> */}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

All imports are done properly.
While running this code the application shows an array that data is undefined.
and produces an error

> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

After referring to the docs it stated that it works only for class components but I am using react functional components. Any idea to solve this issue?

I understood that the "data" usage in pagination is causing errors because the data is undefined before the API call and setData().
Need Help.

Comment: Initialize the `data` property as an empty array, you are trying to slice it and it's value is undefined, that's why you got an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the data is fetched from the newtwork, the value of state variable `data` is undefined, because you declared it so:

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
```

This is same as :

```
const [data, setData] = useState(undefined);
```

I guess the real problem is here:

```js
const filterData = data.slice(start, end);
```

`.slice` does not exist on undefined. You can do two things:

1. Define (Initialize) `data` as an empty array:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

2. Or, you can use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)